# change form action dynamilcally for multipart/formdata

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using JXL to upload file to a servlet but I am getting error like :

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
```

I want to change form action using the radio button selected.For different Document type I am using different servlets for processing.
JXL is not reading the doc because it is not getting uploaded in desired format i think

Below is the code i am using :

```
function changeAction(radio) {
    radio.form.setAttribute('action', radio.value);
}  



<form onsubmit="changeAction(this);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width: 743px;">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="radio" onchange="changeAction(this);" name="doctype" value="servlet1" checked="checked"/> doctype1
    <input type="radio" onchange="changeAction(this);" name="doctype" value="servlet2"/> doctype2
    <input type="radio" onchange="changeAction(this);" name="doctype" value="servlet3"/> doctype3
    </div>
     <input size="70" type="file" name="spreadsheet" id="4" />
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="return filechk();"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: yes its working if i use action="servlet1" or action="servlet2"
but i want to change the action dynamically using radio buttons or dropdown

I get jxl.read.biff.BiffException error when i pass parameters in form.If i exclude that out then everything works fine

Comment: anyone can help me with this??